# Too many battery-indicators in gnome-shell

Tags: 11.10, battery, indicator

For some reason I get more than one battery indicator in my panel. This has the unfortunate side-effect that my PC closes down (only one of them is correct, the rest has 0% battery left).

Comment: You seem to the victim of [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/833397) and the question has already been posted here - [Two battery indicator symbols, how do I get rid of one?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65803/two-battery-indicator-symbols-how-do-i-get-rid-of-one) This is as such a bug-report and is to be filed off as off-topic.