# I have an extra power icon in my menu bar. Any idea why?

Tags: unity, indicator, power-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Two battery indicator symbols, how do I get rid of one?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65803/two-battery-indicator-symbols-how-do-i-get-rid-of-one)

It's a notification area icon (I've set the systray whitelist to 'all'.) It's completely superfluous, unresponsive, and appears not to be associated with any process I can find. Removing the power indicator does not affect it. It appears in every icon theme.

[image: extra power indicator]

Comment: You shouldnt whitelist simply removing everything in gconf/dconf and substituting "all" - reset your settings as per http://askubuntu.com/questions/76215/how-do-i-set-the-panel-whitelist-back-to-the-default/76226#76226

Answer (score 2):

Try `sudo apt-get remove indicator-power` and restart the session.
I had the same problem and that fixed it.