# How do I fix my theme?

Tags: gtk, 11.10, gnome, themes

After installing and using Ubuntu 11.10 for while I decided to install gnome shell. After Installing and rebooting my system I saw that Ubuntu light theme (ambiance/radiance) is gone.

I check `/usr/shar/themes` and `/usr/shar/icons`, it seems that the light themes and mono icons exist. I even reinstalled `gtk3-engine-unico` package but none of these effort fixed my problem :(

my desktop now looks like this:

[image]

What should I do to get my default ubuntu theme back?

Comment: Please see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do

Answer (score 3):

Fortunately I found how to fix my problem, I did these things:

1) went to my home directory and deleted contents of these folders: 
   .cache .compiz-1 .config .dbus .gconf .local (I wasn't sure which folder contains     default theme, so I had to delete contents of all these folders)

2) went to system settings->Appearance and chose my theme

that's all

Answer (score 2):

The typical solution is to remove the accessibility themes like so:

`sudo apt-get remove gnome-accessibility-themes`

`sudo apt-get install gnome-themes-standard`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to delete `.cache` and friends; all you need to do is go to System Settings > Appearance and set a new theme.

Answer (score 1):

Install dconf-editor if you don't have it, and then go to

> org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings

and check "active." One thing I've also noticed when this happens is that the media keys stop working: enable org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media keys. There also might be some more plugins you should enable.

THIS IS THE BEST WAY TO DO IT BECAUSE YOU DON'T DELETE ANY CONFIG FILES!