# Oneiric desktop looks seriously defect after updates

Tags: themes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Desktop forgets theme?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21305/desktop-forgets-theme)

Probably a coincidence, but after applying the fix to [How to get the proper LightDM theme?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63134/how-to-get-the-proper-lightdm-theme) and running the latest batch of updates, my desktop suddenly looked like this after rebooting:

[image: theme and dash defect]

Funny thing is, it seems to be account specific, as my girlfriend's account seems unaffected. I can't logout because the whole entry is missing on the top right. Rebooting doesn't solve the issue. System settings (when run from the launcher) lacks a whole lot of icons and changeing the theme doesn't solve the problem (only changes the window top bar).

I'm going to try the solution in [How do I fix my theme?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59791/how-do-i-fix-my-theme) first, but if that doesn't work (likely, since I seem to have a slightly bigger problem than the one in that question) I'd love something else to try (other than creating a new account).

Comment: Seems like the solution provided in the question mentioned above (deleting the contents of .cache .compiz-1 .config .dbus .gconf .local), actually did fix the problem, although it also reset a lot of customization which I'll now have to redo...

Comment: So a more elegant solution (e.g. narrowing down the list of folders which contents should be deleted) would be prefered. If anyone else runs into this, please try :-)