# PyQt apps cause Window Manager to crash - where's the problem?

Tags: 11.10, python, metacity, pyqt

I've upgraded to Ubuntu 11.10 and I have a strange problem.

PyQt apps, like [ReText](http://sourceforge.net/p/retext/) and the one below, cause window manager to go crazy.

Metacity [crashes](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/797078), Compiz hangs, GNOME Shell / Mutter displays a window with parts of my wallpaper inside.

Example script that causes the problem (which draws a window with QTextEdit and QToolBar):

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QMainWindow()
editBox = QTextEdit(window)
toolBar = QToolBar(window)
window.setCentralWidget(editBox)
window.addToolBar(Qt.TopToolBarArea, toolBar)
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I get these warnings in the output:

```
(python:3489): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_style_get: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
```

and

```
QWidget::setMinimumSize: (/QMainWindow) The largest allowed size is (16777215,16777215)
```

What can cause this problem?

Comment: Ubuntu 11.10 is a [beta release](http://askubuntu.com/q/18641/667) so this is most likely a bug. Please run `ubuntu-bug python-qt4` to report this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this bug report:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qt4-x11/+bug/805303

to run in the mean time install qt4-qtconfig and change away from the default of gtk+ gui styles.