# Nautilus Menu appearing behind transparent gnome-shell menubar

Tags: gnome, nautilus, ppa, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 beta when it was released a couple of weeks ago. Everything is working fine.

Later I installed GNOME shell and then upgraded it from the gnome-shell testing ppa. I also installed and enabled all the gnome-shell-extensions available on the ppa. There is only one problem. When ever I switch to a theme which has a transparent gnome-shell menu I see nautilus menu behind it.

[image]

It only disappears when I quit nautilus. I don't know I to get rid of it so that I can use use themes like Nord and Malys properly.

Comment: what ppa is that?

Comment: Would you provide a screenshot?

Comment: @desgua: here's a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/BisUM.jpg

Comment: Please see: [There's an issue with an Alpha/Beta Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](http://askubuntu.com/q/18641/667).

Comment: This is the gnome-shell testing ppa for oneiric "ppa:ricotz/testing"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That actually happens with the official Gnome Shell packages in Ubuntu 11.10 too (at least for me, at the time I'm posting this answer).

I only know a fix for this: disabling Nautilus from handling the desktop (so using this, you won't have icons on the desktop anymore). To do this, install "dconf-tools":

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Then launch "dconf-editor", navigate to *org > gnome > desktop > background* and uncheck the "show-desktop-icons" box.

Comment: Thanks buddy, I used gnome-tweak-tool to disable nautilus from handling the desktop and now it works

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this is a bug in nautilus that occurs when ever there is no window manager running, and apparently also happens in GNOME Shell. I'm still trying to figure out myself what triggers it specifically, so I can report a bug with the correct details.

I believe it is probably already noticed by the developers however.

Hopefully, as 11.10 is still not at a final release, this bug should be fixed by the release date.