# Standart menu showing with transperant theme

Tags: gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nautilus Menu appearing behind transparent gnome-shell menubar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61105/nautilus-menu-appearing-behind-transparent-gnome-shell-menubar)

I'm using a transparent theme and I can see the menu bar underneath:

[image]