# Top left window corner pixel without clickable function

Tags: launcher, 11.10, ayatana, globalmenu, usability

From 11.04 getting used to quickly push the mouse into the top left corner to make the launcher appear, I have to realize that in 11.10 only the Globalmenu appears.

What's the intended functionality for the top left area, please?

This seems quite bad to me as with many icons in the dash I have to scroll first the launcher upwards to be able to click on the dash icon.

Comment: Please see: [There's an issue with an Alpha/Beta Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expected behavior is that the whole left edge should reveal the launcher bar. The top-left corner should [not extend the close button](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/839690) by design.

However, bottom- and top-left corners don't do that right now, which is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/839677).