# Installing Ubuntu 12.04 Alpha from USB

Tags: installation, live-usb, 12.04

As most of you probably know the Ubuntu 12.04 Alpha has been released.  However there is a bug that makes the ISO file over sized so that it will not fit on a typical 80min CD.  The computer that I wish to use to test it does not have a DVD drive installed or I would just go that route.  I have used various USB installation programs in the past to created Live-USBs, but none of the programs I have used are updated for Ubuntu 12.04 Alpha.  So I was wondering if anybody has been able to install the Alpha from USB and if so, how?  Thanks in advance for your time

Comment: see here: http://askubuntu.com/q/18641/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The over-700MB iso isn't a bug. Bootable USB drives are very convenient!

Look in your Dash for "Startup Disk Creator" (If non-Unity, then it's in the System menu)

The application asks you two questions: Where is the .iso? And which USB drive?
It's very easy and straightforward.

Good luck!

Comment: Wow! That was incredibly simple and I don't know why I've never used the built in start-up disk creator.  Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I use this way to create a bootable USB drive for Ubuntu 12.04, but when I used it to install Ubuntu 12.04 in a physical machine, it hang in the beginning. Only the 'Ubuntu' icon and a progress bar (five shining stars) were in the screen... Any idea? Thanks.