# Playing video on Intel GMA with top-of-the-edge (xorg-edgers) drivers - known bugs?

Tags: intel-graphics

I have 'xorg-edgers' repository enabled. Two to three weeks ago after update, playing video through 'x-video' had become impossible: X server freezes, entire screen starts to blink slowly, then I have to reboot. I'm on Intel GMA video (Sandy Bridge embedded video). Does anybody experience similar problem? Is there bug reported on this?

Comment: What you experience is expected when using pre-release and experimental drivers (see also [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/18641/3940)). You should file a bug on the driver you have problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bug was [filed and instantly fixed](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=44324) upstream! Amazing.