# I think I found a bug but I don't know how to report it

Tags: 12.04, kubuntu, bug-reporting, testing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [There's an issue with an Alpha/Beta Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do)

I have installed Kubuntu 12.04 Alpha 1.

I started Software Updates to update applications. All packages downloaded, but it started to install and it's stuck at 39% for about an half of hour right now. As I don't have a crash report, if it's possible, how can I report this bug?

Comment: 1) This site has a policy of not answering questions about Ubuntu development releases which 12.04 is. 2) You must expect problems like this when running Alpha or even Beta releases. 3) There have been lots of problems with Update Manager in 12.04. This is why some of us use Synaptic Package Manager to do our daily updates. 4) The problems that I noticed with Update Manager on 12.04 seem to have been fixed. I had no problems at 1 a.m. this morning. 5) There is already a very good answer to the question - How do I report a bug? This is basically a repeat question.

Comment: OK. If I have another question about 12.04, where can I go then?

Comment: Go to Ubuntu forums at http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=412. That link will take you to the section called Ubuntu+1 Precise Pangolin. As it is a forum discussions are allowed. which is not the case with this site. You might also want to read these pages https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing. Happy testing.

Comment: You can just delete the question, or it'll get closed eventually.