# kernel panick how to recover

Tags: kernel, data-recovery

I installed unity 5.0 on my Ubuntu 12.04 experimental system. After installation of unity 5.0 plus some normal updates the system still boots but is shutting down because of kernel panik. I tried to recover in the repair mode, however, the system refuses dpkg --configure -a by stating that the files are read only. Same reactions on every installed kernel. Help needed.

Comment: Please see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make sure the disk is in good condition first.

sudo umount /dev/sda1
sudo fsck /dev/sda1

Be careful with this, you don't mention why it's mounting as read only. However, it is possible to re-mount the root filesystem in r/w mode. Try something like this to remount

sudo mount  -o rw,remount -force /dev/sda1 /