# Help PathOfExile on Wine?

Tags: wine, games

Ubuntu 12.04
FGLRX - Catalyst 11.12-2
Unity Desktop - AwesomeWM

Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/38PPrfXk

Launched by: wine / playonlinux

installed packages: Dx9, Dx11, vc2008 vc2005

Err:

`[POL_Wine] 
Message: Running wine-1.3.37 Client.exe`

wine: cannot find L"C:\windows\system32\winemenubuilder.exe"

err:wineboot:ProcessRunKeys Error running cmd L"C:\windows\system32\winemenubuilder.exe -a -r" (2)

p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0
fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0

p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

err:seh:raise_exception Unhandled exception code e0000001 flags 0 addr 0x7b83b362

[POL_Wine] Message: Wine return: 1

Anyone have any ideas?

Game is said to work with wine!

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [There's an issue with an Alpha/Beta Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do)

Comment: If possible, please consider closing some of your other open questions by selecting the best answer (if they have one). Consider which answers have been useful and need an upvote. We need users to maintain their questions so that the site can be an effective tool for the next person with your problems. For more details on best practices consider reading [the FAQ on asking questions](http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask).