# Toshiba Satallite c660 - problems with fan

Tags: fan, toshiba-satellite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [There's an issue with an Alpha/Beta Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do)

I am using a toshiba satallite c660.

I am using ubuntu 12.04 (latest build).

I have problems with my fan, sometimes it runs, than not. I dont understand why. I already  looked at the celsius for the processor cores, they run normal (always under 60 celsius) .

I wanted to use toshset to control the fan by myself , but it outputs:

```
required kernel toshiba support not enabled.
```

Do you know how I can get the module in form of a package for 12.04 (amd64) ?

Or do you know an other way?

Comment: P.S. are you gotwig?

Comment: yes, why are you asking me :D ?

Comment: In doing my research for the problem I ran across your way-too-late bug comment =P

Comment: sry, the notebook is relative new ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rebuild the kernel with Toshiba support. `sudo apt-get source linux-image-3.0.0-16-generic` (or -pae if you're using it).

Then cd to the directory where the source is, should be something like linux-3.* in the folder run `make menuconfig` go to Device Drivers -> X86 Platform Specific Drivers -> Toshiba Laptop Extras. Hit the 'M' key. Then keep hitting Exit until it asks you to save your config. Tell it "yes" and save it as `.config`. Then, use a text editor to open .config and find the line: `#CONFIG_TOSHIBA is not set` and change it to `CONFIG_TOSHIBA=y`. Save and quit the text editor.

```
make
make install
```

^ I'm not totally sure about that last part. You may want a second opinion there. I've built kernels, but I've never installed them. However, if it's sensible and like everything else then that command should get the modules and the re-built kernel installed.

After that, you should *hopefully* have the modules you're looking for.

Oddly enough I was scouring the menu for the kernel and I couldn't find the option for that CONFIG_TOSHIBA anywhere (it was referenced by the Toshiba ACPI driver, but not in the menu... odd)!