# What happened to the new icon theme for 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, icons, design

In the last Ubuntu Developer Summit (UDS), the developers from the desktop team and Mark Shuttleworth announced that a new icon theme is coming for Ubuntu 12.04, but... the Beta 1 is out and still no news of a new icon theme.

Has this being postponed to Ubuntu 12.10 or later?

Answer (score 3):

The new Icon Theme is yet to be released for Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: There isnt going to be a new icon theme most likely since we are past user interface freeze and beta freeze. A login sound and wallpapers are the only ones which are expected.

Comment: Askbuntu.com isn't the place to ask about Ubuntu+1. Please read the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq) and [There's an issue with an Alpha/Beta Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do).

Comment: @Nik, that's the answer.

Comment: @Nik Could you repost your comment as an answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there isn't going to be a new icon theme most likely since we are past User Interface Freeze, Feature Freeze and Beta Freeze. I did not find any blueprints regarding this on Launchpad meaning it has been deferred to another Ubuntu release.

A new Login sound and wallpapers are the only ones which are currently expected to be landing in Ubuntu 12.04 Precise soon.