# Switching to a new user after session is locked

Tags: login, lock-screen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [There's an issue with an Alpha/Beta Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do)

I am running 12.04 with two users and am hoping I am just over looking something. When one user account idles and locks I am unable switch users. Is there a way for another user to log in once the system locks, or must the first user unlock the computer? 
I believe in at least some other distros I get an option on the lock screen to log in as a different user - but that option is missing. Any suggestions about anything i'm overlooking here?

Answer (score 0):

12.04 is still in beta phase and most likely this is a bug. According to 11.04 documentation this should work like this:

"When your screen is locked, other users can log in to their own accounts by clicking Switch User on the password screen. You can switch back to your desktop when they are finished."

I also tried this in 12.04 and it didn't work --> bug should be filed. http://www.ubuntu.com/community/report-problem

Comment: Bug against lightdm is now reported.