# Can't sign-in into the Ubuntu 12.04's Ubuntu-one app

Tags: ubuntu-one

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [There's an issue with an Alpha/Beta Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do)

I'm currently testing Ubuntu 12.04 Beta and first of all! Great work devs!

I just have a little issue I can't resolve by myself... The Ubuntu-One client!

I can't sign-in, the button isn't active and I don't know why...

I tried to remove all ubuntu-one system folders, remove the package, cleanup and reinstall, same stuff... I even reinstalled the complete beta, but I'm still blocked... The Sign-in button is inactive, even by striking enter, nothing happen... Don't ask me if my credentials are ok, there are!

Any ideas?

Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

Known bug, should be fixed in an update next week. Sorry!