# I need help choosing hardware upgrades to get Ubuntu 12.04 3d to run

Tags: upgrade, 12.04

I have a Dell Dimension 3000
RAM: 512 MiB

CPU: Intel® Pentium(R) 4  2.80GHz

Graphics: Intel® 865G x86/MMX/SSE2

What do I have to upgrade to run Ubuntu 12.04 3d.

Comment: possible duplicate of [There's an issue with an Alpha/Beta Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do)

Comment: I posted what I saw from Ubuntu's computer details in system settings. Is what I posted as "Graphics" not the graphics card?

Comment: Just get a Graphics Card, done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a supported graphics card.

Take a look at this list

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsVideoCards

You can find a listing of graphics cards by vendor, and if 3d is supported in Ubuntu as of 11.10.

I would personally use the information to find a old (but not ancient) ATI or Nvidia card for cheap.

Comment: I looked at the supported graphics cards and mine is listed to work with Ubuntu 3d. Do I have to little RAM?

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements - 1 Gb is advised. You can run it with 512, but it will be slow.

Comment: Thanks....that should solve my problem. When I log on selecting Ubuntu 3d it automatically switches to 2d. Would you recommend getting 1gb or 2gb of RAM? Also where would be the best place to buy RAM?

Comment: Your problem with 3d -> 2d is nor ram related, it is video card related.

Comment: Is this my Video Card "Intel 865G x86/MMX/SSE2"? I am confused because the Intel 865G Video Card is listed a supported by 3d.

Comment: See the link I gave you re: filing a bug report on the Beta =)

Answer (score 1):

The requirements for Unity are [HERE](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DemystifyingUnityGraphicsHardwareRequirements).

Also [HERE](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/UnityHardwareRequirements) you have a list of hardware requirements for the Ubuntu 10.04, not much should change 12.04.