# Where can  I check for development progress and report bugs for GNOME classic panels?

Tags: 12.04, gnome-classic

I'm testing 12.04, GNOME classic works better than in 11.10, but there are still some quirks, like for example <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> not working.

Any idea where can I follow the development ?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do

Answer (score 3):

It's actually called Gnome Panel. You can report bugs for it by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and entering `ubuntu-bug gnome-panel`.

It also has a project on Launchpad: https://launchpad.net/gnome-panel