# How to Dual-Monitor in 12.04 with fglrx?

Tags: multiple-monitors, 12.04, fglrx

Just installed ubuntu 12.04 and wanted to get my dual monitor setup working.
Installing fglrx-updates with jockey didn't work so i installed it in the terminal.

Then i setup up my screens in amdcccle (multi-desktop). That way it worked perfectly in 11.10.
Now the only thing i got is a white left screen and on the right screen there is no unity launcher.
If my mouse enters the left screen, the cursor changes to an "X".

If i activate Xinerama in amdcccl both screens work, but i have a top panel on both screens.

Can i get the 11.10 behavior back?

Xorg.conf:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
        Identifier     "amdcccle Layout"
        Screen      0  "amdcccle-Screen[1]-0" 1920 0
        Screen         "amdcccle-Screen[1]-1" 0 0
EndSection

Section "Module"
            Load  "glx"
EndSection

Section "ServerFlags"
        Option      "Xinerama" "off"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier   "0-DFP6"
        Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
        Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
        Option      "DPMS" "true"
        Option      "PreferredMode" "1920x1080"
        Option      "TargetRefresh" "60"
        Option      "Position" "0 0"
        Option      "Rotate" "normal"
        Option      "Disable" "false"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier   "0-DFP7"
        Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
        Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
        Option      "DPMS" "true"
        Option      "PreferredMode" "1920x1080"
        Option      "TargetRefresh" "60"
        Option      "Position" "0 0"
        Option      "Rotate" "normal"
        Option      "Disable" "false"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        Identifier  "amdcccle-Device[1]-0"
        Driver      "fglrx"
        Option      "Monitor-DFP7" "0-DFP7"
        BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        Identifier  "amdcccle-Device[1]-1"
        Driver      "fglrx"
        Option      "Monitor-DFP6" "0-DFP6"
        BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
        Screen      1
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier "Default Screen"
        DefaultDepth     24
EndSection
Section "Screen"
        Identifier "amdcccle-Screen[1]-0"
        Device     "amdcccle-Device[1]-0"
        DefaultDepth     24
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Depth     24
        EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier "amdcccle-Screen[1]-1"
        Device     "amdcccle-Device[1]-1"
        DefaultDepth     24
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Depth     24
        EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Edit 1: If I enable Xinerama i can not get Unity 3D to start. Unity2d starts automatically.

Btw.: I am using an AMD 6850.

Comment: possible duplicate of [There's an issue with an Alpha/Beta Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do)

Comment: I have a Dell M6600 with firepro M8900 ATI gpu, and am also unable to use multiple monitors in a non-cloned fashion in ubuntu 12.04.  I got a segfault in X11's log after rebooting after setting "Virtual" under subsection "display" under section "Screen".

Answer (score 2):

I have the same card (Radeon 6850), but I was able to configure just using amdcccle installed through Jockey.  Here's my generated Xorg, maybe it will help.

Also, you could consider updating to the newest available driver from the AMD site if you've updated your kernel since the last install of your drivers.  Hope it helps.

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "amdcccle Layout"
    Screen      0  "amdcccle-Screen[1]-0" 0 0
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load  "glx"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "0-DFP11"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
    Option      "PreferredMode" "1920x1080"
    Option      "TargetRefresh" "60"
    Option      "Position" "1920 0"
    Option      "Rotate" "normal"
    Option      "Disable" "false"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "0-DFP10"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
    Option      "PreferredMode" "1920x1080"
    Option      "TargetRefresh" "60"
    Option      "Position" "0 0"
    Option      "Rotate" "normal"
    Option      "Disable" "false"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "amdcccle-Device[1]-0"
    Driver      "fglrx"
    Option      "Monitor-DFP11" "0-DFP11"
    Option      "Monitor-DFP10" "0-DFP10"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Default Screen"
    DefaultDepth     24
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "amdcccle-Screen[1]-0"
    Device     "amdcccle-Device[1]-0"
    DefaultDepth     24
    SubSection "Display"
            Viewport   0 0
            Virtual   3840 1920
            Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working by running:

```
sudo amdcccle
```

Then selecting Display Manager > Multi-Display > Multi-display with displays(2)

I then had to reboot and open System Settings > Display and uncheck Mirror Displays. I am running the HD Radeon 6000 series and dual display works fine on my two lovely 26" monitors :-)

Answer (score 0):

if you like to try an alternative, try disper

```
sudo apt-get install disper
disper -l # this will show all recognized monitors/beamers
disper -e # this will expand your dekstop to two monitors
disper -s # will return to single monitor
disper -c # will clone your monitor
```

pretty handsome and safed much of my time to setup my system (e.g. using disper to switch off my laptiops monitor while referencing the two external monitors which are connected through a docking-station)

more details here:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11685035&postcount=3