# Effects still causing issues after uninstalling CCSM

Tags: installation, compiz, uninstall, reset

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [There's an issue with an Alpha/Beta Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do)

I've recently installed and uninstalled CCSM (CompizConfig Settings Manager), and after the uninstall, the effects were still there, and are very buggy. Any tips?

Comment: What is the ubuntu version you use? 11.10 ?

Comment: Nope, 12.04 Alfa 2 (Precise Pangolin)

Comment: 12.04 is approaching beta 2, it's time to update.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know how to update (I'm kinda new to it).

Comment: Do you have to run the development release? Why not try a stable one instead?

Comment: @mikewhatever I don't know whether this should be closed simply because the OP is on 12.04. I could see how effects set using CCSM might stick around after uninstall on other versions of Ubuntu, as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `unity --reset` in a terminal to reset your Compiz settings.

Comment: @JessParker: if this solved it for you, you can mark the question as solved by clicking the green tick next to my answer.

Comment: Yea I know, I haven't tried it yet, but thanks.

Answer (score 1):

CCSM only configures Compiz. As you've seen, removing CCSM doesn't change the setting. CCSM is so buggy that it may not be included in the next Ubuntu release 12.04. There are a couple of applications out there that provide some setting of Compiz. The one that works for me consistently without bus is Ubuntu Tweak. Roland's suggestion of "unity --reset" is a good one to get back to a reasonable starting point. Ubuntu Tweak doesn't provide all the configuration opportunities of CCSM but what it has works. My suggestion is before updating to 12.04 which is still in beta consider trying Ubuntu Tweak as it with 11.10 will give you a stable system. You can get Ubuntu Tweak by following the instructions at http://ubuntu-tweak.com.

Answer (score 1):

Just to mention about installing/removing ccsm. When you install ccsm nothing changes at all other then 2 additional plugin packages are installed. All of the newly installed plugins are disabled by default, so your install is the same

When you remove it nothing changes either, all that's gone is the easiest way to set compiz plugins, whether to improve or sometimes not, & if need be fix.

So if your going to adjust compiz plugins & aren't sure of or remember your changes then probably better to create a new usr. You can fool around all you want to see what's what.

When done or if things get stuffed just delete the user.

Answer (score 0):

as you mentioned in above command , to update your system .

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

do this in your terminal .