# World of Warcraft crashes when entering the game

Tags: wine, intel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [There's an issue with an Alpha/Beta Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do)

I installed WoW and it starts fine, but as soon as I enter the game it crashes instantly. This does only happen in crowded places like major cities, when I login with alts in empty places the game works fine. I have no graphic errors or anything. I'm using a Thinkpad X220 with intel HD 3000 graphics on Ubuntu 12.04 beta 2 with the xorg-edgers repository enabled and updated and Wine 1.4

Answer (score 0):

You can try reducing all you video settings to the lowest possible and pray that works, seems like your video drivers are running low on crowded spaces. You should at least make sure that the software you are trying this is stable and not beta.