# Bug report invalid, unupdated packages

Tags: bug-reporting

I tried reporting a bug to launchpad, and it faulted with

> Please upgrade your system to the latest package versions

I have downloaded Ubuntu 12.04 beta 2 ten minutes before I tried to report the bug.

How can it was possible? What do I need to do now?

Answer (score 2):

When reporting a bug you should (**specially in beta**) make sure that you are using the latest package versions available from the Ubuntu servers.

Since 12.04 beta 2 release as a CD, packages have been already updated with fixes on the servers.

The CD images are not constantly updated (*unless we are talking about a daily image, but these also can be missing some updates right after download*). You need to update your system before successfully reporting a bug.

Do that by opening a terminal and typing `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Make sure that the bug you where going to report is still present on the new packages, a more recent package update might have already fixed it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The bad thign about this is that the error ocurred in installation, and I can't get a update in the installation process, can I?
Also, I get this error from launchpad reporting bugs sending others bugs and with the system up to date, it is possible?
Thank you for the effort

Comment: No, you should not send bug reports using a LiveCD or during installation on beta, those are useless if the CD image is outdated and in the case of beta that is the case. You need to have an updated system to be able to send a bug report. If you are having issues during installation and cannot handle it wait for the stable release or if you want to try to help out solving them follow the instructions on this post http://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do

Comment: Please, can you make an answer from your comment? and then I can check valid the correct answer for the comunity. Also please delete this comment when you are done =)