# STA wireless driver error

Tags: installation, networking, broadcom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [There's an issue with an Alpha/Beta Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do)

I've got this problem installing my wireless driver. Is keeps giving me theis message:

> Check var/log/jockey.log

I've got a Gateway computer. But I don't quite know what wireless driver I need. It tells me:

> This package contains Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driverfor use
>   with Broadcom's BCM4311-, BCM4312-, BCM4313-, BCM4321-,BCM4322-,
>   BCM43224-, and BCM43225-, BCM43227- and BCM43228-basedhardware.

But every time I go to try and install it, it gives me that error. How do I fix this?  I'm running 12.10.

Comment: You need to actually look in the file /var/log/jockey.log to see the actual error. If you don't understand the message in that file, you can open the file with gedit, copy the entire file (select all, then copy), paste it in a pastebin service such as http://paste.ubuntu.com, and then update your question with the URL returned by the pastebin, so we can look at the file.

Answer (score 1):

I have Broadcom 4311 and I checked on Broadcoms site for the latest version, at:

http://www.broadcom.com/support/802.11/linux_sta.php

5.100.82.112 from oct-25-2011, thats the same version that came installed in the Ubuntu 12.04 x64 1.5 GB DVD!! Which means... theres no newer version. Therefore I recommend you to stay on 12.04 until a newer version comes available from Broadcom.

I had that same problem in the past, also recently trying to install Kernel 3.4,  which is not supported yet.

You have to wait.