# Consoles in Ubuntu and automatic upgrade

Tags: 12.04, console, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [There's an issue with an Alpha/Beta Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do)

So I recently discovered that ubuntu is simultaneously running 6 consoles in addition to the GUI that everybody uses, which can be accessed by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1 ... +F6 and then the default GUI with Ctrl+Alt+F7. What use can these consoles have when I can just open a terminal in the GUI mode? Also, why is having consoles like this advantageous for computer users; wouldn't a GUI be much more simplistic?

Also, running the console told me that I was running a development version of Ubuntu Quantal which is version 12.10. The login screen (correctly?) says that I'm running 12.04 LTS. What does that mean?

Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 3):

The console mode is useful for debugging/fixing things, when the graphical mode crashes or fails to load due to driver issues. Most people will never use/discover them.

As for the version number discrepancy, most likely the image for lightdm has not been updated to show the new version number yet, and still shows 12.04. If you've installed 12.10 then you are on 12.10.