# 12.04 LTS 64bit login screen and error windows show 12.10

Tags: 12.04, login, screen, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [There's an issue with an Alpha/Beta Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do)

I installed 12.04 LTS 64bit using the Wubi application alongside Windows 7.  Everything seemed to have gone smoothly, however the login screen shows 12.10 in the bottom left corner.  Also, after the first login before I managed to check for updates etc. some crashes occurred and the reports were showing version 12.10.  I am new to this and I am not sure how I have managed to end up with 12.10 packages. The about window shows 12.04 LTS.  Any cure for the above?

Many thanks,
Kris

Comment: Where did you download the file from?

Comment: From here:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?distro=wubi&release=&bits=

Which is the main Ubuntu download page.  As far as I can remember the Wubi program was downloading an image with amd64 in the name using the torrent network.