# Nvidia drivers with GeForce 680M problem

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [There's an issue with an Alpha/Beta Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do)

I have a new Alienware M17x which I have installed 64-bit Ubuntu 12.10 (dual boot). I have tried various ways to install the Nvidia drivers for the GeForce GTX 680M (which they claim they are compatible with):

- from Ubuntu Software Centre (though Additional Drivers fails to detect the card.)
- using `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`
- downloading the drivers from nvidia and manually installing them (ctrl + alt + F6, `sudo service lightdm stop`, `sudo ./NVIDIA*`, `sudo reboot`)

(each with a clean install of Ubuntu) but in all cases, when I reboot after installing nvidia-setings claims that I am not using the driver and should `sudo nvidia-xconfig` from the terminal, which I do but this has no effect and I am stuck in crappy resolution until I `rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf` and reboot.

The `xorg.conf` that `nvidia-xconfig` generates is:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: I have the same problem with 640M LE

Answer (score 1):

The way I solved this problem, was to install [Bumblebee](http://bumblebee-project.org/) to enable optimus.

For some reason the default video card seen in Ubuntu is the integrated Intel card and installing the Nvidia drivers without bumblebee causes a mess. The installation is pretty painless.  To run your software with the Nvidia chip, you need to open terminal (`Ctrl+alt+T`) then type `optirun` in front of whatever you want to run.

An added benefit is you will get better battery life as the Nvidia graphic card will be turned off when not in use.