# Grive on Ubuntu 12.10 gives: "error while loading shared libraries: libbfd-2.22-system.so"

Tags: 12.10, grive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [There's an issue with an Alpha/Beta Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do)

I've just installed Ubuntu 12.10 and am trying to get Grive working using [these instructions](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/05/grive-open-source-google-drive-client.html).

However when trying to run Grive it gives me the following error:

```
bquast@baq:~/Grive$ grive -a
grive: error while loading shared libraries: libbfd-2.22-system.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I don't know if this matters, but my home directory is on a separate partition.