# How to disable nautilus just-type search?

Tags: nautilus, search, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [There's an issue with an Alpha/Beta Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do)

The new nautilus is nice (even if i miss the f3 split) but the "just type" search is SO annoying in it's interference with my everyday patterns.

I work a lot with remote sftp filesystems and it's pretty much broken by itself and also breaks ordinary navigation. I don't want to "search" as i know exactly where's my stuff and want to get to it with minimal effort.

There's a [bug report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=680118), but that's not quite "bug" and i hope there is something one could do to stop the damn thing from blasting in my face every time i launch nautilus to get somewhere.