# Mounting a disk produces two icons on the launcher

Tags: unity, launcher, mount, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [There's an issue with an Alpha/Beta Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do)

Ubuntu 12.10: 
When mounting a disk (either ntfs partition or inserting a CD/DVD), two icons appear on the Launcher for each particular disk; both of them seem to be identical and work in the same way.

Is it a bug or a feature? If possible, I would like to leave just one shortcut per disk.

(It is interesting that for USB flash drives only one icon appears).