# How do I downgrade Nautilus 3.6 in Ubuntu 12.10 to Nautilus 3.4?

Tags: nautilus, downgrade, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [There's an issue with an Alpha/Beta Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do)

I dislike the new Nautilus. How do I downgrade it?

For those who wonder why I don't just use 12.04; the drivers for my graphics card on my laptop aren't available in Ubuntu, and I didn't want to use Unity 2D.

Comment: You can't do that, I'm afraid.

Comment: It looks like they're going to be adding 3.4 as well as 3.6 to the repositories for 12.10. See this link: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-desktop/2012-August/003921.html and the rest of the messages in that thread.