# No Unity updates in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [There's an issue with an Alpha/Beta Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do)

So, yesterday i've updated my Ubuntu (12.04 -> 12.10) to report bugs and to meet the new Unity.

After the update the Unity looks the same: no "unity previews" or any news.

So, I went to the terminal to see the Unity version that was installed:

```
wlcosta@GLaDOS:~$ unity --version

unity 6.2.0
```

Any ideas about the problem?

Comment: I have `unity 5.14.0` with up to date 12.04. So you have a newer version.

Comment: Make sure you have all the updates installed. Go to the terminal and type: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`