# When will the Humble Indie Bundle 6 games be supported on 12.10?

Tags: games, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [There's an issue with an Alpha/Beta Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do)

Currently, I can see them in the software center, but they say its not supported for my version of Ubuntu. Now, I know 12.10 is just in Beta, but I see no reason why they would not be supported. Is there one?

Is the default setting for such packages to say they are not supported? What is the difference between 12.04 and 12.10 that would make it not supported? I'm pretty sure if I just download the standalone .sh install script its going to work, but I'd rather do so through the software center and get updates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know this questions is considered off-topic by most, but I'm going to answer because I got it to work for the previous humble bundle (Which was gifted to me).

You just need to install the debs as usual, and it will work as if you were on 12.04 (at least it did for me).

Comment: It is off-topic, but that is a correct answer. Used that for 11.10 > 12.04 bundle when I got it earlier.