# Taskbar and ALT+Tab do not show gtkwave application?

Tags: unity, taskbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [There's an issue with an Alpha/Beta Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do)

I have some .vcd files with wave dumps, I use gtkwave application to view those files. I used to use kubuntu, but recently switched to ubuntu (updated today to 12.10).

When the gtkwave opens, it is not added to the left-side unity panel. When it gets minimized, I cannot get it back again.

I test the process existence by **top**, gtkwave is there and running.
Is it a problem with unity or gtkwave? Can I fix?

UPDATE: When I show desktop, then restore all windows, then minimize showing windows one-by-one I find the gtkwave at the back ;) It is still very annoying.

Thanks in advance,
Tarek

Answer (score 0):

Check if it switched to another desktop using <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> keyboard shortcut or Workspace Switcher from Unity Launcher.