# how to enable keyboard layout indicator in gnome-shell?

Tags: gnome, keyboard-layout, 12.10

I upgraded to 12.10 beta 2 and in gnome-shell I don't have the keyboard layout/language indicator in the top panel. I have two layouts enabled and I can switch between them.

I used to have it in 12.04 and also its visible before logging in.

how do I enable it in gnome-shell ?

Comment: It's a bug. For more information, see: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1045914/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This should be [reported as a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) (but check [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1045914/) first, which @user94972 suggested). You may also find [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) and [this one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do) valuable. We'll probably close this as off-topic, as per [the FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq#questions).