# Ubuntu 12.10 + Gnome 3 = Keyboard Layout Indicator is not working!

Tags: gnome, 12.10, gnome-panel, keyboard-layout, gnome-tweak-tool

I have two keyboard layouts, but keyboard layout indicator is only visible on login screen.
After I login to system, I could not see it anymore!

My problem is almost the same as following:
[Question #195194](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195194/how-to-enable-keyboard-layout-indicator-in-gnome-shell)

But, I have the latest release of Gnome Shell, from official Gnome team repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
```

And other packages have the latest versions as well,
so I doubt that this error happens because of a bug.

Already tried the instructions mentioned in this thread:
[Gnome3 keyboard layout icon disappeared](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=118911)

Especially the `gnome-tweak-tool`. Still unable to see keyboard layout indicator.

Please tell me, how to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

It's bug dude and not solved until now.

Please read this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1045914/

Comment: Thank you for the answer! A bit late, but much appreciated! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

After the bug is solved, still you have to find how to have the keyboard indicator in gnome... especially if you upgrade to 13.04.

Please look at my answer at: [Keyboard layout indicator in gnome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281695/keyboard-layout-indicator-in-gnome/353368#353368)