# Problem after the Last Dist-upgrade in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: upgrade, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [There's an issue with an Alpha/Beta Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do)

I just updated my ubuntu 12.10 netbook using the command sudo apt-get dist-upgrade.
The last partial-upgrade has eliminated unity; if I try ro re-install Unity from Synaptic it tell me that I have problem with the dependecies in particular with "compiz-core-abiversion-20120920".
I dont't really know what I have to do to re-install Unity.
Does anybody could help me?
Thanks a lot

[update]
1)  I tried to remove "compiz-core-abiversion-20120920" but I can't remove virtual packages
2) after install and re-install compiz it's always the same
3) I don't know what i must to do...

Sorry for my bad english....

Answer (score -1):

Since Ubuntu 12.10 is still in beta phase, I recommend you to perform a clean install, it will be more accurate than trying to figure out what conflicts are present.