# Problem with dropbox installing

Tags: 12.10, dropbox, beta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [There's an issue with an Alpha/Beta Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do)

Installing in 12.10 beta. This message:
breaks existing package "nautilus-dropbox" conflict: dropbox ()

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Hi and welcome to AskUbuntu. The question you have posted does not fall in the scope of questions discussed here. Please refer to the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq) to see what kind of questions you can ask here. 12.10 is a BETA release Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Open Synaptic Package Manager and remove that specific package (`nautilus-dropbox`). That will eliminate the conflict.