# Ubuntu 12.10 won't upgrade nVidia Drivers

Tags: nvidia, upgrade, apt, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [There's an issue with an Alpha/Beta Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do)

I've been running 12.10 for about a week now with pretty minimal issues so far; the main problem I'm experiencing is that the nvidia drivers I have are refusing to upgrade. I'm currently using the experimental drivers, so I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it. Either way, I was hoping to see if anyone could make any sense of this output:

From `apt-get upgrade`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic ubuntu-desktop
The following packages will be upgraded:
  nvidia-settings-updates
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
308 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,820 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,675 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 207320 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace nvidia-settings-updates 304.43-0ubuntu1 (using .../nvidia-settings-updates_304.51-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement nvidia-settings-updates ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-settings-updates_304.51-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man1/nvidia-settings.1.gz', which is also in package nvidia-settings-experimental-304 304.48-0ubuntu1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-settings-updates_304.51-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What would be the solution to this? I already tried an `apt-get clean` along with a `apt-get -f upgrade` after, and that didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

nvidia-settings-updates and nvidia-settings-experimental are two version of the same software, you shouldn't use them both at a time, or you'd get an error as above. Uninstalling one of them should be fine.