# Unity failure on 12.10 after upgrade from 12.04

Tags: unity, upgrade, 12.10

After upgrade to 12.10, Ubuntu starts as normal however the system only loads the desktop background, the left/upper bars is not displayed and Ubuntu reports that `gnome-control-center` failed.

Problem fixed after un-installing fglrx.

Comment: You should [report this as a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs). (You may find [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do) and [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) useful.)

Comment: Solution for the same issue that happened to me: http://askubuntu.com/a/202782/5496