# X broken after upgrading with an ATI Radeon card

Tags: xorg, 12.10, radeon, opengl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can’t install ATI proprietary drivers in 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202857/cant-install-ati-proprietary-drivers-in-12-10)

I have an amd64 system with an onboard Radeon HD4250 video card.
After upgrading, unity fails to startu due to xorg problems.
Has anyone else had this problem?
How was it fixed?
Any ideas?
(I don't have access to the computer at this time, or I would give more info. If any specific info would be helpful, please specify.)

I suspected it may be related in some way to information provided here:
http://www.ubuntuvibes.com/2012/10/how-to-enable-opengl-30-support-for.html
Which says that the proprietary drivers do not support Quantal's xorg 1.13/opengl 3.0. I had been using proprietary drivers before the update.

I have tried updating to the 3.6 kernel, but I didn't finish the process before having to let it be for the day, but I suspect more needs to be done. The article also mentioned that the HD2400-HD4290 may not even be OpenGL 3 compatible? Frankly, I don't play many games, and I don't care what opengl I'm using so... as long as it works for HD movies and regular us I'm good.

Any suggestions on what direction I should look?

Comment: I have seen others ask this and one suggestion that seems to make sense is to use `sudo apt-get remove fglrx` but no-one has accepted it as an answer so I cannot be sure if it works. http://askubuntu.com/questions/202857/cant-install-ati-proprietary-drivers-in-12-10-unity-is-missing is one example

Comment: Indeed, removing fglrx fixed it for me as well. Others have reported the same thing fixes the problem.

It worked. except the command I used was:
'sudo apt-get autoremove fglrx --purge'

See:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/202752/upgrade-to-quantal-unity-top-bar-side-bar-and-window-declorations-missing/202782

Comment: You could provide this as an answer and accept your own answer, it may help others who have this problem.

Comment: But I'm a n00b, so I have to wait 8 hours. I'll do it later....