# Unity will not load, ccsm settings don't stick

Tags: unity, 13.04, ccsm

When I log in, the only thing I get is a desktop background, but no Unity elements. I can access a terminal, but that appears to be it.

I saw another thread here going on about re-enabling the Unity plugin with ccsm, but that hasn't worked. Every time I enable Unity within ccsm and reboot, it comes back with the Unity plugin disabled.

I am completely at a loss for what to do. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you experience loss of window-decorations?

Comment: Only sometimes, but I can't figure out what, exactly, causes this to happen.
Now that I look at ccsm, it appears that the option to enable Unity is now completely missing. The button to get to the Unity plugin settings is there, but there is no checkbox to enable it.

Comment: check this answer on how to force the settings to be remembered http://askubuntu.com/a/528517/46437

Answer (score 0):

this happened to me on my hybrid graphics laptop.  I changed the driver from the default xorg driver to the fglrx driver and upon reboot--the unity bar and everything was missing.  I right clicked on the desktop to change the display to get the settings and changed back to the xorg driver and rebooted and it worked.

Comment: Could you perhaps elaborate on this a little bit? I see how to get to the settings screen, but I can't do anything about changing drivers from there, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

If you look inside that setting, by clicking on it, on the sidebar at the bottom left hand side should be a button to enable it. This error is common in 13.04+ and has happened to many of them (including me).

There are errors like this dotted all over the place with different answers such as these;

---

[Link 1](https://askubuntu.com/a/204430/167895), [Link 2](https://askubuntu.com/a/204438/167895), [Link 3](https://askubuntu.com/a/202964/167895), [Link 4](http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?284845-Ubuntu-13-04-Parallels-8-no-menus), [Link 5](http://www.tuxgarage.com/2011/04/missing-top-and-side-panels-in-unity.html),

---

There are many more, but just read through a few of these and see if any of them are useful to you, if not we'll explore more options.

Comment: I tried those solutions, and none seemed to work. I think it may be a problem with the proprietary AMD drivers, but I'm not sure. The additional drivers dialog tells me that there are no proprietary drivers installed, but I think there are, since I'm still getting weird underscan problems which were happening before this Unity issue. Is there a way to uninstall these drivers with only a terminal, and not knowing exactly what or where they are?