# 'Web apps' keeps opening another session

Tags: chromium, 12.10, webapps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [There’s an issue with an Alpha/Beta Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do)

I tried searching but couldn't find this (surprisingly).

The new web apps (12.10 b2) itself it working fine in terms of integration to the messaging menu, etc; but I'm trying to figure out why Chromium (v20) keeps opening another instance in the unity launcher (see below). Even if there's no Chromium session running at all, I open it and it still does this.

[image]

Again, everything else works fine but it's kind of (visually) annoying.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.