# Downgrade fglrx on Ubuntu 12.10 for Ati Radeon HD 3650

Tags: fglrx, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [There’s an issue with an Alpha/Beta Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do)

I can't install old Ati Catalyst 12.4 drivers on Ubuntu 12.10 (with 3.2 kernel) which support my video card (Ati Radeon HD 3650 AGP). I purged 12.9 drivers and installed old 12.4 ones, but they don't work.

http://pastebin.com/kz6jNZUT

After reboot I got this:

http://pastebin.com/vzC4Yrbz