# Installing UBUNTU 12.10 correctly on Dell Inspiron 6000 with 2 GB ram

Tags: 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [There’s an issue with an Alpha/Beta Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do)

I installed UBUNTU 12.10 after creating a Disk from the ISO file. Apparently everything installed correctly but after first reboot, system doesnt run. Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 0):

12.10 is the development release and is still in beta.  You should try installing 12.04 LTS, or wait until 12.10 is released in a few weeks.