# How to Stop Ubuntu 12.10 Wireless From Dropping Out

Tags: wireless, connection, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [There’s an issue with an Alpha/Beta Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do)

Appreciate any help.

I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.10 and it's been a nightmare on my Wireless connections. Was fine with release 12.04. I knew I shouldn't have started chasing rainbows but the hype was too much to pass up :)

I first noticed it with my Droid Razor Hotspot connection ... then my UML290 Pantech with a Cradlepoint router and finally I just happen to have a freebie upgrade coming my way and got the Verizon's 4G LTE -890L-3D65 last week and the same issue (Wireless connection keeps dropping out ..sometimes I go for an hour or two , other times a few minutes. No rhyme or reason. I tested the same on my other PCs with Window 7 and XP on the same devices and the connections were/are rock solid. I chased down a few hits on the net but nothing really seem to work consistently and because I use VPN on these computers..wasn't sure to try the WICD. I'm relatively new to Linux anyways so I didn't want to push my luck. Was hoping to put this behind me when the final release comes out soon? Any ideals?

BTW, I use the ethernet connection and no issues. Any promises on the final release or perhaps an easy fix that I overlooked? There's no obvious disconnects.. I notice the bars go down a couple notches and I'm done. Sometimes the bars are full and I'm still done. I wait a couple minutes and it's back up again maybe for a few minutes...maybe even 30 minutes... but the connection will drop...it's aggravating.

Thanks,

Comment: I recently read an article about this or a very similar issue and the workaround a.k.a the solution was to disable IPv6 for the connection. If that is an option for you, maybe it helps. Also, it might help to put the BSSID for your wifi in the network configuration to avoid breaks during scanning for networks.