# Dual Boot - No GRUB

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, windows-7, live-usb, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [There’s an issue with an Alpha/Beta Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do)

- I have Windows 7 installed in a primary partition and wanted to
  install Ubuntu 12.10 in a new partition.
- Even before starting the installation, I knew that I might run into a few problems because the partition I was installing Ubuntu on was displayed **before** the W7
  partition in the Disk Manager of Windows.
- After the install, I didn't get a GRUB menu on reboot but was directly booted into W7.
- A used a LiveUSB to boot into Ubuntu (Try Ubuntu) and ran the BootRepair software with the recommended settings. It showed an unsuccessful, [the result](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1269285/)
- Now, I'm still directly booting to W7, but have access to the LiveUSB. Can someone guide me on how to have GRUB displayed on boot?
- Ran BootRepair again with Advanced settings...the [new results](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1269349/)

Comment: Boot-Repair's PPA has just been updated for your case. Please update Boot-Repair and retry the Recommended Repair. Indicate the new URL that will appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im sorry if im repeating obvious info, but your issue is explained by this line from the output

```
 => Windows is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
```

While installing linux do you remember if a prompt turned up asking where you want to **install the bootloader**? If you get this prompt (its usually just after the one asking where you want to install ubuntu) you need to insist in the strongest terms that it be installed in **MBR of sda**, i.e the place where the windows bootloader is installed right now, that *should* now allow you to boot to both windows and linux after that.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue before,

If you have 2 hard disks , try to turn the other hard disk to defult hard disk from boot setting.

If you don't want to do that. Just go to boot menu and select the second hard disk to boot.

If you don't have 2 hard disks but only 1 , Please tell me what else do you see when you don't see the grub menu

Comment: I only have one hard disk...using a laptop.
I see:
Windows encountered a problem : Recovery Mode | Boot Windows normally

Comment: Then You must have restarted manually after installing Ubuntu.
This is common broblem. When installation is done, the grub menu is still not installed even they ask you to restart. You should restart from Linux not Physically. Can when it is restarting , it is making the grub menu

Comment: Umm..I restarted with the restart button that the Ubuntu installer provided. Not physically.
Anyhow, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Sorry , the best way I know is to Reinstall it from Live USB and you better use 12.04 LTS cus the 12.10 is just released and will be full of bugs for a while.
I recommend you to use 12.04 LTS