# How to test other DE in Ubuntu 12.10 live (alpha)

Tags: live-usb, lightdm, 12.10, desktop-environments, logout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [There’s an issue with an Alpha/Beta Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do)

*caution: 12.10 is not yet released but I was told it will say as is also when release happens (live session)*

So, new ubuntu live session does not have option to "logout" and choose different desktop environment (DE).

This function was usable if one installs ubuntu live on USB stick with permanent changes. One can install any software, including KDE (plasma) or LXDE. Until including 12.04, one could simply logout and choose different DE.

Now, there is no "logout" option in top right menu and if ran `service lightdm restart` it automatically logs in to live session account with unity.

Answer (score 0):

Does the live cd let you change to the tty login by pressing `CTRL+ALT+F1` ? If so you might be able to `killall lightdm` and then try `kubuntu-desktop`. That's what i would try. (-=

Comment: I already tried something similar, but lightdm is configured to auto login to "live". Also kdm didn't really worked as expected.