# How can I connect to Nexus 7 (running Ubuntu) via SSH?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

I just installed Ubuntu on my Nexus 7 and works like a champ, but I can't connect via SSH/Telnet/RSH from my laptop. I've installed openssh-server, telnetd-ssl and rsh-server, but still can't.

The connection is made, but it hangs after typing my password.

```
$ ssh ubuntu@192.168.1.70  
ubuntu@192.168.1.70's password:
```

I'm running Ubuntu Raring 13.04 on a Nexus 7 32GB

Thank you.

Comment: Raring Ringtail is in beta, and thus not supported here, making this question off-topic.  See the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq)

Comment: See also [There's an issue with an Alpha/Beta Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do)

Comment: @iSeth not offtopic or the wiki is wrong see questions section https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7

Answer (score 0):

I have just installed Ubuntu 13.04 on a nexus 7.
The steps were, in a terminal on the nexus:

```
$ apt-get install openssh-server # answer y
$ ifconfig wlan0 # to find nexus IP address
```

Then, on a computer in the same wireless network,

```
$ ssh loginname@ip-address

The authenticity of host '192.168.131.40 (192.168.131.40)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is 54:22:d3:ea:2e:af:b2:87:23:74:1a:ce:f5:e5:e4:11.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.131.40' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
loginname@192.168.131.40's password: 

The programs included with the Ubuntu system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Ubuntu comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by
applicable law.

Welcome to Ubuntu Raring Ringtail (development branch) (GNU/Linux 3.1.10-8-nexus7 armv7l)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

loginname@nexus:~$
```

Comment: That's what I did, but I couldn't login via SSH. I'm going to reinstall Ubuntu and see what happens. Thanks guys!

Answer (score -2):

Login with the user you created during the installation. But make ssh more verbose, should tell you were it is hanging.

```
ssh -vvv ubuntu@192.168.1.70
```

Comment: I already tried with the user I created during the installation and also with root, but still can't login.

Comment: so you tried user@192.168.1.70 ?