# Compiling RTL8192CU Driver for Edimax EW-7811UN for Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring Ringtail)

Tags: wireless, drivers, compiling, 13.04

Yesterday, I upgraded to Ubuntu Raring 13.04 and can no longer compile the latest RTL8192CU driver from the Realtek website (3.4.4_4749-2012/11/12).

Raring Ringtail runs under kernel 3.8.0-1-generic which does not appear to be compatible with the current Realtek driver.

Unfortunately, solving these compiler errors are a bit beyond my ability and any help would be appreciated.

```
/tmp/rtl8192c$ sudo make
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/3.8.0-1-generic/build M=/tmp/rtl8192c  modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-1-generic'
  CC [M]  /tmp/rtl8192c/core/rtw_cmd.o
In file included from /tmp/rtl8192c/core/rtw_cmd.c:23:0:
/tmp/rtl8192c/include/osdep_service.h: In function ‘thread_enter’:
/tmp/rtl8192c/include/osdep_service.h:575:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘daemonize’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
In file included from /tmp/rtl8192c/include/drv_types.h:69:0,
                 from /tmp/rtl8192c/core/rtw_cmd.c:24:
/tmp/rtl8192c/include/rtw_recv.h: In function ‘rxmem_to_recvframe’:
/tmp/rtl8192c/include/rtw_recv.h:626:30: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/tmp/rtl8192c/include/rtw_recv.h:626:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/tmp/rtl8192c/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/rtl8192c] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-1-generic'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  Since 13.04 is still in development, such questions as yours are off-topic until closer to the release. http://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do

Comment: 13.04 has been released